# update record without page refresh in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a span in which dropdown is taken here dropdown records are with checkbox option .

If I select "All" checkbox & click on save button then all checkboxes are selected using ajax therfore page is not refreshed but when I does not check any checkbox & click on "Save" button I give a confirm box but when user press "Cancel" button on confirm box the the page is refreshed and data will not change, I want same but without this page is refreshed on cancel button

Comment: Do you want the cancel button to unselect everything?  Is that what you're asking?  Does your cancel button submit a post request?  What is it currently doing?

Comment: I want previous checked values when I click on Cancel button

Comment: So you basically want a page refresh--without the page refreshing?

Comment: If you could post us a code snippet of what you're working with, we'd be more than happy to help you figure out what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

In the JavaScript code section, please add this statement at the end of the block:-
"`return false;`"

This above statement will make sure that the page does not get POSTed / submitted when the "`Cancel`" button is clicked.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want previous checked values when I click on Cancel button

Comment: @user739154 - Please try to understand the logical way of thinking & please correct me if I'm wrong in mentioning the following situation.  
Point is say you have 7 check boxes (let's mark them as `c1`, `c2`, ..., `c7`) with another one of "`All`". Now by default, when the page loads, it shows as `c1` to `c3` as checked & others as non-checked. Now if you change the selections of the check boxes & click "`Cancel`", then logically the page won't load up & you can't get back the previous values, as all of this is happening in the client-side. I hope that this point gets you going.

Comment: @user739154 - You probably have two options only - either you use AJAX, when clicking the "`Cancel`" button, to load up the last checked values (which makes sense, as AJAX won't do any page refresh), or the user / visitor must refresh the web page manually to get back the previous checked values. Hope it helps.